# SIP Android app, how to use services and activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service, sip

I would love is someone could point me to some good resources or in the right direction, or even better pump out some code snippets/pseudo code to help me here.

I'm new to android devel and I've been tasked to create an app which uses a sip library to make/recieve sip calls. The library is fairly abstracted and all works with a 'phone' instance which I can call .rejectCall(), .answerCall() and so on and so forth. To get the instance of the phone, i use this line:

```
AbtoPhone abtoPhone = ((AbtoApplication)getApplication()).getAbtoPhone();
```

Thats all fine and dandy, but not understanding Activities and Services properly I'm not sure how to go about turning it into an app.

I want the ability for a user to log in, register with a sip server and then let the phone will listen for calls.

I want it to continue to listen for calls when put into the background. And when in background I want to pop up a dialog that allows someone to answer or reject call, and on answer I want the intial activity to wake up (or if its been killed then i want it to start up) and be brought to the foreground so the user can chat away merrily.

How do I best go about it? At the moment I'm getting the AbtoPhone in the main activity, adding the account, adding all the listeners, and then when a user hits the register button it starts a sticky service which gets its own instance of the phone, with the same command as before.

Then, within the service, I register the user with the sip client. Now when I close the main  activity this continues to run and it will receive a call, however it will crash with an exception:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window 
-- token android.os.BinderProxy@4154ebb0 is not valid; 
is your activity running?
```

I get that my problem is the original activity that called the service is dead and I'm trying to wake it. But I just don't know how to do that properly.

I get that Services and Activities is a repeated question, and I have looked around read tutorials however I cant see how to properly apply them to my case, and just hoping someone will be able to say Do X, Start service, Pass this, When you get a call do Y and VOILA! But any help what so ever will be greatly, greatly appreciated!!!

Cheers,

DJOodle

**>>>> EDIT**

Ok, I've moved all handling of the AbtoPhone to a service. When i get a call i then invoke the MainActivity, bind it to the service, so i can invoke the correct methods to answer the call.

This is fine and it works however this means I've got a persistent service that is always running, and i get the feeling that's a bad, bad thing. How can i keep an instance of AbtoPhone listening away for incomming calls without draining the resources of the phone?

Cheers!

Comment: Did u know how to get audio stream from abtophone instance during call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a big topic. I think you should give Sip-Droid which is an open-source application a chance. so you can use anything related to it.

```
http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/
```

this is a Sip based application that does everything you asked for. I think you can use the source code and redeveloped anything you want from it. 
this application uses JNI which is more complicated topic than Sip. so use all JNI's in this app and you will find lots of lib that you can use and make the works faster.

Comment: Im gonna mark you as the answer as i found mine within the SipDroids source and its been a big help, so thankye!